# is it possible to update paypal's adaptive payments lightbox display options?

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments

we are using paypal adaptive payments embedded solution so our buyers can stay on the site during checkout. we want to change the lightbox CSS. how can we do it? after looking at the PP adaptive payments API documentation all we could find was headerImageUrl. how do we changed the header logo? can the background be changed?

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame"> 
<input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light">  
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller_1328179547_biz@complexintegrations.com">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="6">
<input type="hidden" name="headerImageUrl" value="https://domainname.com/images/LOGO%20%281%29.png">
<input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="AP-4N0030004W852052F"> 
<input id="GetShippingAddresses" type="hidden" name="GetShippingAddresses" value="1"> 
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/bnr/bnr_MSPFbanner_ec2_143x32.gif" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal" style="height:22px;position:relative;top:5px;">   
</form>      
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var dgFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({ trigger: "submitBtn" }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this on the Lightbox.

There's unfortunately no way to customize it, beyond changing the width of it (And you have to manually hack the JS for that.)